# Client side application with save to disk ability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a new project. It is more or less a "client management" program with very simple functionalities:

- adding a client
- deleting client
- adding some infos
- etc...

I wish that nothing has to be installed in order to make the application work and the application will have to at least run on Windows and OS X.

The only thing I can think of is to build my application in HTML/Javascript. This application will only run on the client-side and as I don't want the user to have to install Apache or anything like that, PHP/ruby (etc..) are unfortunately out.

Another tricky thing is that data will have to be saved to the disk as I don't want the user to have to install SQL or any other database core. It will also be good to be able to encrypt the data so nobody can actually open the file and understand what is inside, I am thinking XML might be the solution, however I haven't find much resources on how to encrypt/save/decrypt/parse xml file to the disk in Javascript.

Please tell me if you think my idea is appropriate, I am eager to learn new languages so any idea is welcomed!

Comment: * I forgot to mention that some users will not have access to the internet, so using an external database will not be the perfect solution, thanks.

Comment: as web developer planning to use client side only (no internet or cloud), why not try developing on Adobe Air. you can develop apps using html and/or flash and take advantage of local storage. i have tried it already.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript really does not have I/O capabilities because do you really want people saying random stuff to your hard drive?

Modern day browsers have [local DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) that you can hold data in the browser, but the user can easily wipe away this info. You would need a "cloud" solution where you upload the data to your server so people can have the data if they delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, by cloud storage, you mean having a database online somewhere that the application will connect onto ? This could work, but some of the users that will be using my application will not have an internet connection, so this is another limit that I forgot to mention... (I have added a comment to my question). Thank you.

Comment: All I am saying is a user can delete the local storage and everything is lost. It is the same as deleting the file on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this through web services, if all the clients are running on the same network. You've said that they might not have an internet connection.

You would have to create a web service app in .NET or whatever you use there & put it on a local server. Your 'server' app can save the data or files.

Your client application, running in that network would be able to run off of that webservice...you should be able to add/update/delete records.

You'll be doing a lot of JavaScript/jQuery/JSON, but it's possible.

You'll also have to find a way to make your web service secure, or anyone in the network that has some knowledge of how web services work can access it directly